# Reason for failed MOSFET and Power Resistor

Tags: power-supply, mains, switching

I am trying to repair the Power Supply for a Phillips TV (the power board is named DPS-130QP). I quite quickly found a burnt out resistor (R611). And after removing a heatsink on a nearby MOSFET (Q601), I found the MOSFET to be split in half as well.

This is all nice and well, and it's quite easy to replace. However, my problem is that I cannot really understand why these components failed. My understanding and experience with switched mains power supplies are however 
very limited.

I've checked all components involved in the driver circuit (driven by IC601), and I've not found any component which seems to be faulty. There are at least no shorts and resistances seems to be reasonable according to their markings (sadly the schematic does not list component values).

My current two theories are:
- R611 failed (it does not conduct any more), causing IC601 to overdrive the MOSFET, which in turn overheated and split open.
- IC601 failed, causing the MOSFET to overheat bringing R611 with it.

I have no way of testing the function of IC601, so this is currently guessing. I'm hoping someone with some experience with Mains power switching supplies can help out with some input. Are any of my theories reasonable? Are there anything specific I should be looking for?

The MOSFET (Q601) is a STP5NK80Z, and the driver IC (IC601) is a ICE2QS02G. The Resistor (R611) is 0.47 Ohm 2W.

The schematic of the relevant part of the supply is here.
[image]

Comment: Based on the schematic I would guess that IC601 is a critical conduction mode flyback controller which is used to chop the high-voltage B++ bus down to 12V. R611 is to transduce the Q601 current into voltage for cycle-by-cycle current limiting. Check for failed/shorted electrolytic capacitors or a shorted load (i.e. one of the DC rails). Also check to see that the boost PFC stage generating B+/B++ (Q80 and IC801) has no faults, but be careful (B++ is likely around 400VDC).

Comment: i never say never, but resistors never fail. not firstly anyway, unless they are not matched correctly, which on a production device, seems unlikely.